# Masking input with optional alphabet prefix to a phone number format

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, validation

I know of this nice jquery plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/
for Masked input, and I can use it fine.

So let's say I want a field to be masked by this format: `+999 9 999 9999`
That's fine, and it's working.

The issue is that sometimes within the field, my users also have the option of giving some text before the number.

So the two inputs that are valid for a user are:

- `+999` `9` `999` `9999`
- `any optional alphabet letters and special characters (but not digits!)` `+999` `9` `999` `9999`,

So for example, this is a valid user input: `+966 1 484 1122`.

And this is also a valid user input: `Phone #: +966 1 484 1122`.

How can I make this mask?

### Edit

For the second type of input, there are actually a finite number of alphabetical prefixes possible, like these:

- Phone: +999 9 999 9999
- Phone +999 9 999 9999
- Phone # +999 9 999 9999
- Phone #: +999 9 999 9999
- Call: +999 9 999 9999
- Call me: +999 9 999 9999
- Call +999 9 999 9999
- Telephone +999 9 999 9999
- Telephone # +999 9 999 9999
- Telephone: +999 9 999 9999
- Talk +999 9 999 9999
- Contact: +999 9 999 9999
- Contact # +999 9 999 9999
- Contact #: +999 9 999 9999

Basically, just the usual possible ways of telling users to "call" at a given number. For this problem, let's assume the prefix can only be the above words. So that means the format for the prefix is usually `Call|Contact|Talk|Phone|Telephone`, `optional #`, `optional :`.

And the overall mask is something like:
`optional Call|Contact|Talk|Phone|Telephone` `optional #` `optional :` `+999 9 999 9999`

Comment: IMHO, you can't mask this input. It's too far complicated ( e.g. is `P+966 1#: +966 1 484 1122` a valid input ?

Comment: No that's not valid, only letters and a couple of special characters like `#` or `:`. I've edited the question.

Comment: maybe you just need to create two forms, one for the beginning text (like Phone:) and the second is the phone number with masked input of course

Comment: I could, but I need it all in one field for the user interface.

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regular expression:

```
var phone_mask = /^[^0-9]*\+9{3}\s9\s9{3}\s9{4}$/;

phone_mask.test("Phone: +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Phone +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Phone # +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Phone #: +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Call: +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Call me: +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Call +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Telephone +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Telephone # +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Telephone: +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Talk +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Contact: +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Contact # +999 9 999 9999")
phone_mask.test("Contact #: +999 9 999 9999")
```

Here is a commented breakdown of the regular expression:

```
var phone_mask = RegExp("^[^0-9]*"/* Optional non-numeric characters */ +
                        "\\+9{3}" /* Followed by a plus sign and three nines */ +
                        "\\s9"    /* Followed by a space and one nine */  +
                        "\\s9{3}" /* Followed by a space and three nines */ +
                        "\\s9{4}" /* Followed by a space and four nines */ +
                        "$");
```

Comment: wow thanks a lot, i just saw this. hope this helps anyone else with the same requirement. but i've left that job now ^ __ ^