# Optional prefix in masked input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, mask

I'm using this Masked Input plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ for my field input.

This plugin allows for optional fields easily enough, such as for example a telephone extension.

`Anything listed after '?' within the mask is considered optional user input.`

This is a solution for something being optional at the beginning:

[jquery masked input have only first number optional rest mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371025/jquery-masked-input-have-only-first-number-optional-rest-mandatory)

I'm trying to have a prefix of the telephone format `+999 9 999 9999`, where the prefix can be one of the words: Phone, Call, Contact, and then optional a colon `:`.

```
$.mask.definitions['~'] = '(Phone|Call|Contact)?(:( )?)?';
$("#en_Phone_Number").mask("~+999 9 999 9999",{placeholder:" "});
```

This doesn't work. Any help?

Comment: Why are you asking this for the second time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385366/masking-input-with-optional-alphabet-prefix-to-a-phone-number-format#comment23484887_16385366